# HtmlService input type=file

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have the following form :

```html
<body>
    <form method='post' action='<?=url?>'>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><h1>foo</h1></legend>
        <label for='fooUpload'>foo</label><br />
        <input type='file' id='fooUpload' name='fooUpload'><br />
        <input type="submit"/>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
```

and i am trying to access the fooUpload file, from my doPost, using

```js
Logger.log(typeof(requestInfo.parameter.fooUpload));
Logger.log(requestInfo.parameter.fooUpload);
```

The first one returns string and the second one returns the title of the file.
Am i doing something wrong? I even trying setting the form as enctype="multipart/form-data"
but that resulted in null and null

Comment: This might be a bug. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Giannis, there's a better way to do this that's currently not working (we are working on a fix). If you scroll down on this page to "forms" and search for processForm(), you'll see an example of how we *want* this to work. Here's the bug we're using to track progress: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1660

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have one minor objection to the suggested solution. What happens when javascript is disabled on client?

Comment: Do you have any numbers as to what % of your users don't have JavaScript enabled? I'm asking because I don't know off the top of my head if HtmlService will work 100% without JavaScript. You certainly lose ALL of the ability to make function calls to your script inline.

Comment: Shouldn't we degrade gracefully for the 1%? Templated scripting works with   javascript disabled?

Comment: HtmlService will not work at all with JavaScript disabled. This is not something we really can or will fix.

Answer (score 1):

When doing file uploads you must set the enctype to "multipart/form-data", as per the [HTML form specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype). However, there appears to be a bug in Apps Script where the uploaded file's Blob is not added to the event's `parameter` field like it should. Please file an issue for this on our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to get updates.

Comment: As per @eric-koleda I added a ticket to this [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2229)