# POST Gzip Data to Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to upload a large data set to a google Apps Script from another web service.
I would like to use Gzip Compression and (I set a Header for AutomaticDecompression DecompressionMethod.GZip).  However when I do so, I get a 400 Bad Request Error.  Does Google Apps Script servers support Automatic Decompression?  (I tried a workaround using a File Upload, however the e.Parameter does not show file Blobs as noted in this  [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785232/htmlservice-input-type-file/11957475#comment19358616_11957475)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  I was sending the data stream compressed as Deflate not as GZip.